# How to show the printed document in new tab?

Tags: java, pdf, browser, pdf-generation

I want show the printed document in new tab when user clicked on print button. I already set the response MIME type as 'application/pdf', But it is not showing the pdf in browser. Can you please suggest me.

Thanks,
Vara Kumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the parameter TARGET = "_blank" to the  HTML tag, which will cause the URL specified in the href parameter to open in a new window or a new tag depending upon the option set in the browser.